# Cake; To freeze or not to freeze?

Tags: freezing

I need to make a wedding cake, the wedding is in 5 days. Can I bake it, stack the layers, crumb coat it and the freeze the crumb-coated layers? Ideally, I want to finish decorating the cake on the day of wedding, we are traveling to the wedding site two days prior to the wedding. 
I know I won't have anyway to refrigerate the cake once I arrive at the venue the day before the wedding, so I was thinking the frozen cake would have time to thaw and acclimate before I apply the final buttercream. There won't be any fondant on this cake. 
I've never tried freezing like this ... can I get away with it, or will the condensation kill the cake?

Answer (score 1):

For the 1st question: can I freeze the crumb coated layers? 
Yes, you can. I've tried it before and afterwards you can smooth it out further.

As for the thawing frozen cake within 2 days, that would heavily depend on your buttercream type. 
If the climate is hot and you don't use a stable buttercream, I definitely won't recommend it. 
In my experience meringue based buttercream holds better than american type buttercream.
Hope this help.